# Popup view controller shows dark background when user navigates to another view controller without closing the current pop up view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, popup, uitabbarcontroller

I have a table view which is inside a tab bar. When I click the table view, it shows a popup view controller like this:

[image]

But, whenever I navigate to another tab bar, leaving the pop up view as it is without closing it, and when I come back to the previous pop up view, it shows a dark background as shown is the picture below:

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

*Note = I am new to IOS

code for adding my sub views:

```
import UIKit

class NotificationViewController:   UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var dataALL = [NotificationDataModel]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewAll: UITableView!

@IBOutlet  var mainSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

lazy var iNotificationViewController : INotificaitonViewController = {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    var viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "INotificaitonViewController") as! INotificaitonViewController

    self.addViewContollerAsChildViewcontroller(childViewContoller: viewController)
    return viewController

}()

var activityIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableViewAll.delegate = self
    tableViewAll.dataSource = self
    let nib  = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableViewAll.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
    setupView()
    tableViewAll.separatorStyle = .none
    self.startShowingIndication()
    downloadAllJSONData {
        self.tableViewAll.reloadData()
        self.stopShowingIndication()
        print("sucess")

    }
}

func downloadAllJSONData(completed : @escaping ()->()){
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.swipecrafts.com/notice/get")else {return}
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("cf7ab8c9d4efae82b575eabd6bec76cbb86c6108391e036387f3d5356a582171519367747000", forHTTPHeaderField: "api_ky")
    let postdata = "school_id=\(SCHOOL_ID)"
    request.httpBody = postdata.data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil{
            do{
                self.dataALL = try JSONDecoder().decode([NotificationDataModel].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                    print(self.dataALL.count)
                }
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}

private func setupView(){
    setupSegmentedControl()
    updateView()

}
private func updateView(){
    iNotificationViewController.view.isHidden = !(mainSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)



}
private func setupSegmentedControl(){
    mainSegmentedControl.removeAllSegments()
    mainSegmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "General Notification", at: 0, animated: false)
    mainSegmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "All Notificatoin", at: 1, animated: false)
    mainSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    mainSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

}
@objc func selectionDidChange(sender: UISegmentedControl)  {
    updateView()
}

private func addViewContollerAsChildViewcontroller (childViewContoller : UIViewController){
    addChildViewController(childViewContoller)
    view.addSubview(childViewContoller.view)

    childViewContoller.view.frame = view.bounds
    childViewContoller.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    childViewContoller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


}
private func removeViewControllerAsChildViewController(childViewController : UIViewController){
    childViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    childViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataALL.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewAll.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.customInit(noticeTitle: dataALL[indexPath.row].notice_title!,noticeDiscripetion: dataALL[indexPath.row].notice_description!)
    let downloadedimage = dataALL[indexPath.row].image_name
    if downloadedimage != nil{
        cell.lblImageNotificaiton.downloadedFrom(link: downloadedimage!)
    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPopUpViewww", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? PopUpViewController{
        destination.notificationfianlData = dataALL[(tableViewAll.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
    }

}
func startShowingIndication(){

    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()


}


func stopShowingIndication(){
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()


}


}
```

Comment: Is your popup a regular UIViewController sub-class?

Comment: yes it is @LGP .

Comment: can you please share some code ?

Comment: @JenJose i have added my code can you please check it!

Comment: I have a idea which overcome this problem but first say how can you open popup? [1] by UIView or [2] by UIViewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [UIPopoverPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller).

Normally when you present something in the manner you've describe, a user should not be able to navigate away from the parent view controller without first dismissing the "popup" or "popover" view. So even if you don't go with UIPopoverPresentationController you should consider dismissing the popover view via any taps outside of it.

**Update 4/3/18**

I would definitely recommend researching and reading some documentation or following some tutorials so you can understand exactly what code does what and why. If you haven't already the documentation link for UIPopoverPresentationController that I provided above points you to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_transient_content_in_a_popover), which is pretty much exactly what you need.

Here's an example with some of your code.

```
lazy var iNotificationViewController : INotificaitonViewController = {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "INotificaitonViewController")
    // may want to set the viewController.preferredContentSize here => which will be the size of your popover
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    if let popoverPresentationController = viewController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.delegate = self
        // set the .sourceView and .sourceRect so that the popover can position itself and arrow accordingly
    }


    present(viewController, animated: true) {
        // closure for when the popover is visible
    }
    return viewController
}
```

As mentioned by @Britto Thomas you really shouldn't be adding your popover as a child but presenting it.

**Update 4/9/18**

Apologizes, I forgot to add this tid bit, which is very important. Since popovers are intended for iPads you have to implement this delegate method as follows:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Otherwise it will simply present it as any other modal, despite the fact that we told the 'modalPresentationStyle' to be '.popover'

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are presenting popupviewcontroller over the context of NotificationViewController. Using Perform Segue "goToPopUpViewww".

Instead of that please try to present popupviewcontroller over the context of UITabBarController. This makes more sense. This change situation as - when a popup is presented user can't switch the tab.

Comment: and in this case how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

So you are presenting a Seague Modally, You can try to change the presentation style (e.g over current context) of the seague programmatically or through story board, it might help in this scenario.
Please see the screen shot[image]

Comment: In this example current context is the main thing to change.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example project from Apple documentation that was converted to Swift 3. It uses a custom `UIPresentationController` to modally present ViewControllers and also controls how they are animated on and off screen. Follow the same approach and you shouldn't have any issues with dark backgrounds.

https://github.com/ooper-shlab/CustomTransitions-Swift